# Java- Overloading and Overriding Concept

Tags: java, inheritance

```
class Base {

    int value = 0;

    Base() {
        add();
    }

    void add() {
        value += 10;
    }

    int get() {
        return value;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    Derived() {
        add();
    }

    void add() {
        value += 20;
    }
}
```

When calling the derived class constructor and then `add()`, the value becomes 40. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out for yourself what is happening exactly, you could run your code in a debugger and step through it to see what happens step by step.

This is what happens:

1. When you create a new `Derived` object, the field `value` in the `Base` part is first initialized to `0`.
2. Then the constructor of the superclass `Base` is called. This calls the `add()` method.
3. The `add()` method is overridden, so the version in class `Derived` is called, which adds `20` to `value`; so `value` is now `20`.
4. Then the constructor of `Derived` is called. This calls the `add()` method again.
5. Again, the `add()` in class `Derived` is called, which adds `20` to `value`.
6. The result is that `value` contains the value `40`.

[Paragraph 12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) of the Java Language Specification explains the rules of how new objects are initialized, and in what order things happen.

Comment: from base class constructor how method from derived class is called, why not base class method...

Comment: @Yogendra123 - Because that is how overriding works!   All call to the method in the class >>and in its superclasses<< become calls to the override method.  The only exceptions are calls to `super.<methodName>` (e.g. `super.add`) or private methods with the same signature that are never overridden.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the constructor, the `value` field is incremented by 20 when you call the `add()` method. You then call the `add()` method again, which adds 20 to it again, therefore, `value` is 20.

Answer (score 0):

When a subclass such as your Derived class is initialized. It calls the constructors of its superclass, in this case Base. So in this case add() is called twice, both in the constructor of Base and in the constructor of Derived.
Because add() is overriden in Derive, calls to add() on a Derive object will yield 20. Even if the call was made from within Base where the add() method returns 10.